# VB.NET How to get result in text from SQL Query

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2000

With this table :

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(
ID INT,
NAME VARCHAR(30)
)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1,'a')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(2,'b')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(3,'c')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(4,'d')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(5,'e')
```

And this Query :

```
print '-----------------------'
select * from #TEMP
print '******************************************'
```

I need to get the result in text like :

```
-----------------------
ID          NAME
----------- ------------------------------
1           a
2           b
3           c
4           d
5           e

******************************************
```

I can get it with SQL Server Management Studio when I select "result in text" or "result in file".
How can i get this result by VB.Net?

The las query is only an example. this is my real need :

[image]
......

I'm on MS Server 2000.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can take the query results and put them into any form you like. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: You're really better off just formatting it in the front-end instead of trying to force SQL to output the query results with all the necessary dashes and asterisks.

Comment: I just use an existing query. This query have 2000 lines and it print a report. I agree, it's not the good solution, but I do not want rebuild the query

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ADO.NET` and a [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx):

```
Using stream = New StreamWriter(path)
    stream.WriteLine("----------------")
    stream.WriteLine("ID          NAME")
    stream.WriteLine("----------------")
    Using con = New SqlConnection(YourConnectionString)
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from #TEMP", con)
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read()
                    stream.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1)))
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    stream.WriteLine("******************************************")
End Using
```

[**How to: Write Text to a File**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Note that the `Using` statements ensure that the objects are even disposed in case of an exception.

Comment: Your solution will work normally, this query was only an example. I just updated my question with my true queries

Comment: I want load my .sql file, execute, and get result in file or string

Comment: @jonlabr: maybe i've misunderstood the requirement. You want to know how to create sql queries from a Textfile1, execute them and create a Textfile2 with the results? Note that a text file is not a proper input for a sql sommand. You might be open for sql-injection. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb669091(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I already have the .sql text file. It is the image in the question. Now i need to get the result in another file. I know that i can execute it and loop with a reader and write each line in a file. But the line '----------------------' are not in the result.